# Google Analytics - Regex for excluding sessions where Custom Dimension is populated in Custom Report

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I'm building a custom report in GA UA to check which pages aren't passing specific custom dimensions. The Dimensions of the report are:

- Hostname
- Page

The metrics are:

- Pageviews
- Sessions
- Users

What I'm expecting is to be able to add a filter with the following syntax to only get pages where the custom dimension isn't populating:

Exclude [Custom_dimension] Regex .*

When I do this however, the report excludes all sessions. If I change from exclude to include though, I only get the subset of sessions where it's populating, roughly 30% of sessions.

Is there a way to get the 70% of sessions not covered by [Custom_dimension] by changing the regex?

Comment: is it possible that only 30% of sessions do have those missing dimensions in events?

Comment: Yep, that's entirely possible. Trying to figure out how to filter the report for the 70% that have null values for those custom dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GA explicitly doesn't show rows in custom reports for any instances where any of the dimensions is not set. While it's definitely an odd solution on GA's part, you still can do a few things.

You can view, say, a default page report and drop a secondary hostname dimension there and then see where it's not set, or even try to filter those with advanced filter's regex.

Or you can export some of the data in BQ and inspect it there with no UI limitations.

Or you can export the data in an excel or google sheet to analyze it there. there are free options.